# What is the Most Efficient Way to Access Elements in an std::map?

Tags: c++, iterator, stdmap

I have an `std::map<some_type, std::vector<another_type>>` as a static variable in a class. I want an object of said class to correspond to an element in the vector of the map. My immediate thought was to just use store an iterator to both the vector and the map, but I also thought about storing a copy of the key, so that I could use `map::find` to look up the the value associated with it. Which way is recommended or more efficient?

**code**:

```
class example_class
{
private:
    static std::map<some_type, std::vector<another_type>> my_list;

    some_type::iterator map_it;

    // I could either use this
    std::vector<another_type>::iterator location_in_vector_it;

    // or this
    some_type copy_of_key;

public:
    // the constructor creates a new element, or adds the value to the end
    // of the vector in the preexisting element.
    example_class(key, val);
};
```

Comment: What do you want to have happen if the class is copied?  How does the element get removed after an object is destroyed?  Do the vectors in the map grow/shrink?

Comment: Have you measured and profiled to see that accessing the map the "natural" way (using `my_list[key]`) is really a bottleneck? What is the *real* problem that you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: Tangentially related, since you are asking about efficiency: `std::unordered_map` is generally faster than `std::map`, *O(n)* instead of *O(n log n)* for most operations.

Comment: @NathanOliver I didn't think about the class being copied, thank you for pointing that out! and the destructor is going to take care of removing the elements from the vector. The vectors in the map will grow and shrink.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I haven't done any measuring or tests. I'm not necessarily trying to solve a problem, I'm just trying to learn and gain insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way is to write code that is correct, easy to understand, and makes sense. As for efficiency:

- Storing an iterator of a `vector` is a bad idea if the `vector` can grow, as [`vector::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) can **invalid**ate iterators.
- Storing an index into a `vector` (if that is an option -- how can these vectors change?) allows an element to be obtained in **O(1)** time, but in your case you still need to find the vector.
- Storing an iterator of a `map` would allow you to find the vector in **O(1)** time, and this iterator remains valid after the `map` is modified (unless you remove the entry to which the iterator points).

  - Storing a reference to the `vector` within the `map` is similar to using an iterator, and may lead to more readable code.
- Storing the key and using [`map::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) would allow you to find the vector in **O(lg n)** time. This approach can handle the case where the vector you are looking for has been removed from the `map`.

So the **safest approach** is to store the key and index, and write code to handle the cases where the element cannot be found. But.... *Is that a thing that should be able to happen?* Do you want to allow your object's element to be removed by someone else (presumably another object of the same type)? Probably not, since each object is supposed to "correspond to an element". Is this a problem with your design?

**If I was doing this**, I probably would want to ensure that my object's element could not be rudely taken away. One way to do this is to use [shared pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). Instead of storing `std::vector<another_type>` in the `map`, I might consider storing `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<another_type>>`. Depending on what is supposed to happen upon object destruction, I might change that `shared_ptr` to `weak_ptr` so that the static container does not maintain data for objects that no longer exist. In either case, each object could maintain its own `shared_ptr` to its element. This allows fast access to the element and ensures that the element will not be destroyed before the object is.

Of course, the most desirable approach would depend on the reason you need to store these elements in a static container.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store an iterator to a vector in `my_list` if the size of `my_list` changes (except if you reserve everything before).

The easiest is to store the key and then the index in the vector, assuming that you are only pushing back new elements and never removing old ones. The best would be the iterator in the map with the index.

Comment: Accord to the Iterator Invalidation table in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container, iterators of associative containers remain valid after insertion, no matter what.

Comment: Easiest, maybe not the best indeed. Added the note.

Comment: There's also no requirement that the mapped type of an associative container be copyable or moveable, which means the vectors are not going to be copied or moved after creation. The iterators will always remain valid. Note that vector iterators remain valid even if the vectors _were_ moved